# Can't match any of this subject with preg_match

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to match some of the Javascript on a Youtube video page. The pattern thats the same for every video is like this:

```
<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"somethingsomethingsomething\">
```

I need to get out everything in `value`, in this case `somethingsomethingsomething`. It is commented out because this is embedded in Javascript. This is the code I'm using:

```
preg_match('<param name=\\"flashvars\\" value=\\"(.*)\\">', $ytPage, $match);
```

`$ytPage` is the source code of the youtube page. But when I run the code `$matches` never returns a match.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should surround your regular expression with delimiters, for example slashes.

```
preg_match('/...../', ...);
```

Example code:

```
$ytPage= "<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"somethingsomethingsomething\">";
preg_match('/<param name=\\"flashvars\\" value=\\"(.*)\\">/', $ytPage, $match);
print_r($match)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <param name="flashvars" value="somethingsomethingsomething">
    [1] => somethingsomethingsomething
)
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/786UI)

If you are trying to parse HTML you might want to consider if an HTML parser would be a more suitable tool than regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry, `$matches` was a typo. The real variable is called `$match`. The fixes you mentioned above also don't work. But I think I've found the problem. Only part of the Youtube videos source code is being returned in $ytPage. I don't know whether this is a restriction from cURL (the way I'm getting the page) or if it's something else... but now at least I know this part works. Thanks for your help :)